# How to listen to screen touch in background

Tags: java, android

How can I listen to screen touch while my app is in background.

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
```

This method is to be triggered when user touches somewhere

Comment: If your `Activity` is in foreground and your override this `onTouchEvent()` method ins your Activity, then this method will be triggered. But your your App is in background that means your Activity is paused or stopped. For that case above method will not be triggered.

There is a similar question. You can check here https://stackoverflow.com/a/35540369/6200296

Comment: you have to use accessibility services. Google It!